# First Letter - Each Word Upper Case except business type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a UDF which will make the first letter of each work in a column upper case. My issue is that I want to add some exceptions to this and I cannot figure out how to do this.

In my database I have a column of business names - for example - mikes coffee shop, llc.

My function right now will return - Mikes Coffee Shop, Llc.   I want LLC to be in caps while the rest of the business name is correct.  Any thoughts on how to modify this function so that things like LLC or INC are made all Caps?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InitCap] ( @InputString varchar(4000) ) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Index          INT
DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(255)

SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
SET @Index = 1

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                     ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                END

IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', 
'(')
BEGIN
    IF @PrevChar != '''' OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S'
        SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
END

SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

RETURN @OutputString

END
GO
```

Comment: Yes - just don't. Store the strings EXACTLY as you want to see them. You will always - ALWAYS - have exceptions that you cannot predict. To see this in action, just go google "locksmith". I see QuickPro Locksmith LLC, J&M Locksmith, Access-A-Lock, 7Mondays Locksmith LLC, STL Locksmith, etc. I have a phone from OnePlus.

Answer (score 1):

If interested, here a function which can be extended if needed.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('old mcdonald'),
('dr. Langdon ,dds'),
('b&o railroad'),
('john-m-smith'),
('CARSON/jACOBS'),
('jAmes o''neil')

 Select *
       ,ProperCase = [dbo].[svf-Str-Proper](SomeCol)
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol             ProperCase
old mcdonald        Old McDonald
dr. Langdon ,dds    Dr. Langdon ,DDS
b&o railroad        B&O Railroad
john-m-smith        John-M-Smith
CARSON/jACOBS       Carson/Jacobs
jAmes o'neil        James O'Neil
```

The UDF if Interested

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[svf-Str-Proper] (@S varchar(50))
Returns varchar(max)
As
Begin
    Set @S = ' '+Replace(Replace(Lower(@S),'   ',' '),'  ',' ')+' '
    ;with cte1 as (Select * From (Values(' '),('-'),('/'),('\'),('['),('{'),('('),('.'),(','),('&'),(' Mc'),(' O''')) A(P))
         ,cte2 as (Select * From (Values('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M')
                                       ,('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z')
                                       ,('LLC'),('PhD'),('MD'),('DDS')
                                 ) A(S))
         ,cte3 as (Select F = Lower(A.P+B.S),T = A.P+B.S From cte1 A Cross Join cte2 B ) 
    Select @S = replace(@S,F,T) From cte3
    Return rtrim(ltrim(@S))
End
-- Syntax :  Select [dbo].[svf-Str-Proper]('old mcdonald phd,dds llc b&o railroad')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to handle exceptions with `REPLACE`:

```
...
SET @OutputString = REPLACE(@outputString, 'Llc.', 'LLC.');
SET @OutputString = REPLACE(@OutputString, '...', '...');

RETURN @OutputString;
```

It's a good practice to end each statement with semicolon.