# First Name field must not contain 3 consecutive characters with same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help in writing a SQL query to find First Name's that contain 3 consecutive characters with the same value. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: `ASCII(SUBSTRING()) - ASCII(SUBSTRING()) = 1`

Comment: I assume this is some form of exercise? Because arbitrarily telling people that their names are invalid can cause all kinds of issues

Comment: This seems like an extremely contrived business rule. If this is for learning that is one thing but in the real world this is likely going to cause an issue. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: It's only for learning purposes. This was the example i was given

Comment: Variable length names, and any consecutive 3 characters?

Comment: @SeanLange - we were talking about this today, there was a craze about 10 years ago of auto-apply the 'correct case' to names like MacDonald, and our bosses wanted to copy it - a flawed concept

Comment: Yes. Sorry to clarify. Variable Length First Names, but any 3 consecutive charcters except from 'iii' so Valid examples : 'Keeevin', Michellle' Invalid : Miiitchel

Comment: you kept that under your hat that 'iii' does not count

Comment: @Cato Just for fun... regarding a proper case, take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824454/first-letter-each-word-upper-case-except-business-type/50824688#50824688   You can add ' Mac' to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, specs are becoming more clear. This is one of the most ugly solutions ever, performance will be terrible, but nonetheless:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #T AS T
WHERE ColA LIKE '%AAA%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%BBB%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%CCC%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%DDD%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%EEE%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%FFF%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%GGG%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%HHH%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%III%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%JJJ%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%KKK%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%LLL%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%MMM%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%NNN%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%OOO%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%PPP%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%QQQ%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%RRR%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%SSS%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%TTT%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%UUU%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%VVV%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%WWW%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%XXX%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%YYY%' OR 
     ColA LIKE '%ZZZ%'
```

First attempt:
Your question is a bit vague, but from my understanding, you need this:

```
USE TEMPDB

CREATE TABLE #T (ColA VARCHAR (10))
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('AABB'), ('AAAA'), ('CFED'), ('CCCD')

SELECT * 
FROM #T AS T
LEFT JOIN #T AS T2 ON T.ColA = T2.ColA
WHERE LEFT (T.ColA, 1) = SUBSTRING (T2.ColA, 2, 1) 
  AND LEFT (T.ColA, 1) = SUBSTRING (T2.ColA, 3, 1)
```

Comment: So can you please explain what this is doing? Thanks

Comment: Well, you could run the code and see what it does...  It basically compares the values of ColumnA to itself. Hopefully it does what you wanted. If not, let me know.

Comment: This only gives me first names with 2 consecutive values. e.g. Aaron, Peeter

Comment: @K1205 Great, then please accept it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Just another option is using an ad-hoc tally table and a simple join

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (FirstName varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('Johnnny')
,('Susan')


Select Distinct A.*
 From @YourTable A
 Join (Select Top 255 S=replicate(char(Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))),3) 
        From master..spt_values
       ) B 
   on  charindex(S,FirstName)>0
```

**Returns**

```
FirstName
Johnnny
```

Comment: Yeah, I think so

Comment: @Sami Always best when they supply sample data and desired results... eliminates  any confusion

Comment: Yeah, then the answer will be easy ;)

Comment: @Sami You're right.  That would eliminate the fun part.

Comment: Sorry : Sample Data of results that would be acceptable : 'Keeevin' , 'Miccchael' 'Reeece' 'Davvvid' They have to come one after the other i.e consecutively.

Comment: @K1205  In my example, you may notice Susan is excluded, but Johnnny (with 3 n's) is selected

Comment: I noticed, but when i run it it also picks up names like Abigaila just because the name contains the letter 'A' 3 times but is not consecutive.

Comment: it didn't pick up 'Abigaila' when I ran it - it wouldn't do either, because it seems to generate all possible strings of '3 the same in a row' then it checks for their existence - very informative, and very clever.

Comment: right so if i have this table can i do the following if i already have data and don;t require an insert? :   Select *
 From Core.WeccoParty wp
 Join (Select Top 255 S=replicate(char(Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))),3) 
        From master..spt_values
       ) B 
   on  charindex(S,FirstName)>0

Comment: @YourTable is your table, FirstName is the name in that table - have you got SQL to try this on?

Comment: @K1205 I suspect it picked-up Abigaila not because of 3 a's, but perhaps 3 spaces?

Comment: I have some data available to try this on yeah. My table name is Core.WeccoParty and my field name is FirstName

Comment: @JohnCappelletti See why is understanding the question is the half of the answer? I was thinking it's `ABC` not `AAA`. Anyway good catch ;)

Comment: @Sami We're all guilty of over-thinking things.  I'm a simple guy, so that does not happen too often for me.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing a CTE to split out the individual characters of each word. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367283/split-a-string-into-individual-characters-in-sql-server-2005) should help you. The results of this CTE should be something like the following (assuming first names of `John` and `Ericcc`):

```
+---+----+--------+
| i | ch |  name  |
+---+----+--------+
| 1 | E  | Ericcc |
| 2 | r  | Ericcc |
| 3 | i  | Ericcc |
| 4 | c  | Ericcc |
| 5 | c  | Ericcc |
| 6 | c  | Ericcc |
| 1 | J  | John   |
| 2 | o  | John   |
| 3 | h  | John   |
| 4 | n  | John   |
+---+----+--------+
```

Then you can just use successive self-joins (or `LEAD`/`LAG` functions) to figure out successive characters.

Since this is for learning purposes, I won't spell out the answer. If you want to take this approach, and have a specific problem after making an attempt, you can post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the records with length > 2
then apply the second filter to get those matching 3 repeating chars
somehing like this:
select firstname from table 
Where

len (firstname)>2 and
substring (firstname,1,1)=substring(firstname,2,1)

and substring (firstname,2,1)=substring(firstname,3,1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - first it forces each row to have a unique ID (you may already have this)
then I break the strings into individual letters using a recursive CTE - then I see if I can JOIN a letter to the previous and next character, so the 3 rows joined will always be 3 contiguous letters
I then check if the 3 contiguous letters are equal in a WHERE statement
Matching rows are the sumarised using GROUP BY

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ColA VARCHAR (10))
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('AABB'), ('AAAAXX'), ('CFKKKED'), ('CCDDD')


;WITH FORCE_ROW AS (SELECT *,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ColA) RN FROM #T WHERE LEN(cola)>0),
      LETTERS AS (
                    SELECT cola, RN, SUBSTRING(ColA,1, 1) X, 1 AS N FROM FORCE_ROW
                        UNION ALL
                    SELECT cola, RN, SUBSTRING(ColA,N + 1, 1), N + 1 FROM LETTERS WHERE N <= LEN(ColA) 
                  )

select l1.cola from letters l1 
            JOIN letters l2 on L1.rn=l2.rn  and l1.n + 1 = l2.n
            Join letters l3 on L3.rn=l2.rn  and l2.n + 1 = l3.n
            where l1.x=l2.x and l2.x = l3.x
            GROUP BY l1.RN,l1.cola

drop table #t;
```

--also for you to try 
-- stoppress, now does not pick up the English name Keviiin

```
;WITH M AS (SELECT MAX(LEN(cola)) ML FROM #T),
 NUMS AS (SELECT 1 N
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT N + 1 FROM NUMS WHERE N < (SELECT ML FROM M))
SELECT distinct cola from Nums n1 
                cross join Nums n2 
                cross join  Nums n3 
                CROSS APPLY 
                    (SELECT ColA from #T WHERE n1.n +1 = n2.n and n2.n + 1 = n3.n and n3.n <= len(cola)) DQ
        WHERE substring(cola,n1.n,1)  = substring(cola,n2.n,1)                                      
              and
              substring(cola,n2.n,1)  = substring(cola,n3.n,1) and substring(cola,n3.n,1) != 'i';
```